# Creating new pandas dataframe from orginal one and naming using unique value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create several pandas dataframes with names are unique values in a column of orginal pandas dataframe. For example: given orginal dataframe as in the picture:

[image: Orginal dataframe]

I would like to create new dataframes for every ticker from this orginal dataframe. Here I have:

```
In: df.Ticker.unique()

Out: array(['AAPL', 'AXP', 'BA', 'CAT', 'CSCO', 'CVX', 'DIS', 'DOW', 'GS',
   'HD', 'IBM', 'INTC', 'JNJ', 'JPM', 'KO', 'MCD', 'MRK', 'MSFT',
   'NKE', 'PFE', 'PG', 'TRV', 'UNH', 'UTX', 'V', 'VZ', 'WBA', 'WMT',
   'XOM', 'MMM'], dtype=object)
```

I can do it manually by:

```
df_APPL = df.loc[df['Ticker'] == 'AAPL']
df_AXP = df.loc[df['Ticker'] == 'AXP']
...
df_MMM = df.loc[df['Ticker'] == 'MMM']
```

I wonder if there is a faster way than this one.

Comment: `{k:d for k,d in df.groupby('Ticker')}`

Comment: @Quang Hoang: Thanks. But I wonder if there is another way to create seperated dataframes rather than to create a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the tickers and save each DataFrame in a dictionary, with the ticker name as the key:

```
dataframes = dict()
for t in df["Ticker"].unique():
    dataframes[t] = df.loc[df['Ticker'] == t]
```

And this loop can be simplified to a dictionary comprehension:

```
dataframes = {t: df.loc[df['Ticker'] == t] for t in df["Ticker"].unique()}
```

**UPDATE:**
Alternatively if you want to create the DataFrames as named variables (i.e. have a DataFrame called `df_AAPL` with all the AAPL rows), with one for each ticker, you could use the `exec` function:

```
for t in df["Ticker"].unique():
    exec(f"df_{t} = df.loc[df['Ticker'] == t]")
```

Be warned this has the potential to cause difficulties when it comes to debugging your program though, as you will be programatically  creating variables which aren't explicitly declared anywhere in your code. This also assumes that each value in the `Ticker` column doesn't contain any characters which are invalid Python identifiers, otherwise Exceptions will be thrown.

Comment: Is there a way to create seperated dataframes, not a dictionary?

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain how the DataFrames can be created as variables, but generally I would warn against this approach as it is less explicit and harder to debug.

Comment: For the first method, what if I want to create also several dataframes for Date for each dictionary element Ticker? For example, I have Ticker AAPL and inside this ticker I also create minor dictionary for the day 22/04/2019, 23/04/2019, ...

Comment: You would just need to add more levels inside the loop; i.g. `for date in list_of_date_times: ...` and then add further filters to the dataframe based on the dates. The results would then need to be a nested dictionary, where the first level of keys is the tickers, and the second level of keys is the dates.

Answer (score 0):

```py
items = list(df.Ticker.dropna().unique())

for i in range(len(items)):
  vars() ["df_"+items[i]] = df.loc[df['Ticker'] == items[i]]
```